# Mapping tuple types within tuple types

Tags: typescript, types

The docs for [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) offer this example:

```
type MapToPromise<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Promise<T[K]> };

type Coordinate = [number, number]

type PromiseCoordinate = MapToPromise<Coordinate>; // [Promise<number>, Promise<number>]
```

But what if my original tuple contains other tuples, and as part of the mapping I want to pull the interesting values out of those inner tuples?

e.g.

```
// I just want the numbers, but there is other stuff in the type
type MessyCoordinate = [
    [string, number],
    [string, number]
]
```

I had expected I could do this:

```
type Clean<T extends [string, number]> = T[1]

// Why doesn't this work?
type MapToClean<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Clean<T[K]> }

type CleanCoordinate = MapToClean<MessyCoordinate>; // [number, number]
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '[string, number]'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.(2344)
```

I can try adding more constraints on `MapToClean` but it doesn't seem to help:

```js
type MapToClean2<T extends [string, number][]> = { [K in keyof T]: Clean<T[K]> }
```

I can also get rid of the `Clean` utility type and just do this, but it doesn't work either:

```js
// Why doesn't this work?
type MapToClean<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K][1] }
// Type '1' cannot be used to index type 'T[K]'.

type CleanCoordinate = MapToClean<MessyCoordinate>; // [number, number]
```

Is my fundamental expectation that I should be able to bust open the tuple inside the mapping flawed? Or am I just missing some magic bit of syntax to have `T[K]` look like `[string, number]`?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8QGED2qBOATAlgOwENhoBeKAbQFgAoKOi+YDfAcwBoo8BXAWwCMIGALpsa9Bk1Ydu-QUJrzqoSFGQAbCATwAeACpQIAD2J4s8CczztOvAcIB8UMrvIBGRTQD0nqAHUAFiBQWKgIeADkwFDA-jjmAO6YANYA-DTK0DAEYLqo6po6uo5kAN4UANJQ+FBJECCoAGZQukIAXKoaWnrk5UKOAL406eDQ+VpomLiExE6w2bljOnCIKOjY+EQQ9gDcUN4UMnbStnJAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem here is that the `T` in `MapToClean<T>` is not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type whose properties are `[string, number]`.  You could add an appropriate constraint and then it would work:

```
type MapToClean<T extends { [K in keyof T]: [string, number] }> =
    { [K in keyof T]: Clean<T[K]> }
```

---

A less obvious problem is why a constraint that specifically needs `T` to be an array type will still fail:

```
type MapToCleanOops<T extends [string, number][]> =
    { [K in keyof T]: Clean<T[K]> } // same error
```

*That* problem is an outstanding bug in TypeScript, [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  When you map over a tuple with a mapped type, you'll get a tuple out. But the compiler doesn't realize that inside the definition of the mapped type: see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847).  For now, the workaround there would be to do something to inform the compiler that the property will be of an expected type; usually with the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu):

```
type MapToCleanOkayAgain<T extends [string, number][]> =
    { [K in keyof T]: Clean<Extract<T[K], [string, number]>> } // okay again

type CleanCoordinate2 = MapToCleanOkayAgain<MessyCoordinate>; // [number, number]
```

You could have used `Extract` to fix your original `MapToClean` without constraining `T`:

```
type MapToCleanOkayUnconstrained<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: Clean<Extract<T[K], [string, number]>> } // still okay

type CleanCoordinate3 = MapToCleanOkayUnconstrained<MessyCoordinate>; // [number, number]
```

But you probably do want that constraint or it will allow you to pass weird things in:

```
type BeCareful = MapToCleanOkayUnconstrained<{ a: 1, b: ["", 4], c: false }>;
/* type BeCareful = { a: never; b: 4; c: never; } */
```

It's up to you.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8QGED2qBOATAlgOwENhoBeKAbQFgAoKOi+YDfAcwBoo8BXAWwCMIGALoca9Bk1Ydu-QUJrzqoSFGQAbCATwAeACpQIAD2J4s8CczztOvAcIB8UMrvIBGRTWXQYBMLtTqmngA6pgA1vB6BsYQpuYA3hQA0lD4UGEQIKgAZlC6QgBcFlI2ssJQAL6OJGL0ieQpaRlZuflFgVp6DUKOFTSe4NAdeGiYuITETrC+-sOhGBHacIgo6Nj4RBD2ANxQAPR7FDJ20rZy-dQDKj5+ARpaAPKoYJH6RiZmxVanZULkPU5anR6o08OlMjk8oVVPcdC4kgCKvtDvACDxoIIMJgLl5prdhg8wgQQABBFgEfBRd6xT7kRiWazHOT-apAqAg1Jg5qQtowoLaACixgwBAAxsAugiOHTJN9SnYer1kVBUESQFACOT8DjBnytKN1hMIAAmKY3WawwnEskUnTLJAG8abHbK8hMjA-BU664zO5BK0gACqeFFqDw9NtECwelZtDqyU54JaUPasMFwrFEvhIi+jLODiVBygjBwajUKrV3qGsMdG2IAGYzb6CWrg6Hw0xI9H7asxnWtrsi27857zkpdQAhCDIAgYCDZLjlsjmv2PVshsMR-BR7SJAhFVwcPhFcgAIlPHAALDnRUVsgQ1PBoFVtjQ9gAqKC4qczucLpfshqRR4BAABugi7MeUCXrst6cGBEGVFA757DQQA)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, but perhaps I should ask it separately?

I was surpried to find that a value of this mapped type was not iterable ("must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator."). It works on Playground, but not on my local machine (running tsc 3.9.3).

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that you will map the `MessyCoordinate` to get the `number` then why do you complicate your task ?

```
type MessyCoordinate = [
    [string, number],
    [string, number]
]
type MapToClean<T> = { [K in keyof T]: number }
type CleanCoordinate = MapToClean<MessyCoordinate>; // [number, number]
```

Comment: Maybe `MapToClean<[["",1],["",2],["",3]]>` should result in `[1,2,3]` and not `[number, number, number]`?

Comment: @jcalz depends on what OP wants, thats not what I understood from his question

Comment: my answer responds to his specific need, it's not a generic answer for the problem he raised

Comment: I've simplified the problem to try to make it easier to follow, sorry.

I have a general question about being able to pull items out of the inner tuple. In my use-case, I won't know in advance what those types are, and they will be different to each other.